# Finding the tangent line of a level curve at $(1,1)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the point on a level curve through point $(1,1)$ through which the tangent line is vertical given the function $f(x,y) = 3x^2y^2+2x^2-3x+2y^2$

So I was thinking about it, and I thought that this should happen when the slope is approaching infinity.
I decided to calculate the partial derivative $f_y(x,y)$ which is $f_y(x,y) = 4xy^2+4y$ and set it to $0$, to which the only real solution is $y = 0$.
Yet, I'm not really sure what else I need to do in order to find the $x$ value which is supposed to be $\frac{3}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{41}}{4}$.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: If the tangent line is vertical, it means that you can write it as $x=constant$. Since it passes through $x=1$, it means that $x$ is always $1$, so it can't be the value that you think it's supposed to be.

Comment: I think it's the level curve that is supposed to pass through $(1,1)$, not the tangent line.

Comment: @Andrea I think the OP is referring to the level curve of $f(x,y)$ which passes through $(1,1)$ namely $f(x,y)=4$.

Comment: Yep its the level curve which passes through $(1,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(1,1)=3+2-3+2=4$, so you're looking for where the tangent line to the curve

$$3x^2y^2+2x^2-3x+2y^2=4$$

is vertical. Differentiate both sides implicitly and solve for $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$:

$$3\left(2xy^2+2x^2y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)+4x-3+4y\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=0\\
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{3-4x-6xy^2}{(6x^2+4)y}$$

The derivative is undefined for $y=0$, at which point

$$2x^2-3x=4$$

which is easily solved.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why I get $\frac{3}{4}\pm 4$ wherby the actual answer is only $x = \frac{3}{4} + 4$?

Comment: Both points meet the conditions. The book should have given both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation of $ y = 0 $ from $f_y = 0 $ is correct. Having found $ y $, you need to find the corresponding value of $x$ on the line curve.

The equation for the line curve at $(1,1)$ is $f(x,y) = f(1,1)$, i.e. the set of all points where $f$ has the same value as at $(1,1)$.
By substituting $x=1, y=1$, you have $f(1,1) = 4$, so the line curve has this equation: $$3x^2y^2+2x^2-3x+2y^2=4$$
Simply substitute $y=0$ in this curve equation to find $x$.